# Printing array of objects in table (Angular JS)

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects like this one:

```
$scope.sales = [
{id: 15, location:'neverland'},
{id: 16, location:'farawayland'},
{id: 17, location:'highland'}
];
```

This array I am trying to display in a table, it should look like this:

id    |   location

---

15    |    neverland

---

16    |    farawayland

---

17    |    highland

My html :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="sales[0].id">
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in sales">
        <td>{{x.id}}</td>
        <td>{{x.location}}</td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

The input field with value 15 gets printed. It works if I also ask the 2nd or 3rd value. But the table consists of 3 empty rows.

If I add an index (even `<td>{{x[0].id}}</td>`), I get a server error.

Comment: Right-click and choose "inspect element." That will make it clear if the content is actually there, but just not displayed. This could happen if your CSS is not appropriate.

Comment: @Amyblankenship Already did that. There is no content, just empty <td>

Comment: What you are showing should work fine. Create a demo that reproduces this...very simple to set one up in plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me, check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kNTxlKTIqOigKZ1EDFzL?p=preview).

Maybe you are missing something else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">
  <input type="text" ng-model="sales[0].id">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in sales">
      <td>{{x.id}}</td>
      <td>{{x.location}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller("Controller", ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.sales = [{
    id: 15,
    location: 'neverland'
  }, {
    id: 16,
    location: 'farawayland'
  }, {
    id: 17,
    location: 'highland'
  }];

}]);
```